# Send hotkey combinations to remote Mac?

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop

I'm working on another Mac remotely, via the Screen Sharing app. Is there a way for me to send my swipe gestures and "hotkey" keystrokes to the remote machine?

It's kinda annoying to have to keep minimizing "Lion fullscreen" apps to switch back and forth. In the interim, I've set up hot corners, but it's also clunky, because my MacBook is 13" and the remote machine is a 27" iMac.

Comment: Related: https://discussions.apple.com/message/15261127#15261127

Answer (score 1):

Screen Sharing.app's support is pretty limited; while its never ideal to rely upon a third-party solution, you might want to check out the excellent [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com).  It's free for personal use, cross-platform, and has iOS versions available.

Comment: I know about TV, didn't get it working properly, behind corporate VPN etc.

Comment: Really?  It's my org's preferred solution for supporting remote users/laptops etc, I have yet to see a situation where it failed - other companies, hotel business centers, crazy home NAT setups, etc.